# TypeError: Invalid calling object at exports.delay with JSZip generateAsync method promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-addins, excel-addins

I am getting error mentioned in title while trying to zip a text file. I am trying to create an excel addin using js api(react). Error happens on calling "then" in promise. Below is the code which i have used.

```
try {
    //const fileblob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' });
    var zip = new JSZip();
    //zip.file(pgrange.values[0][0], fileblob); 
    zip.file("Hello.txt", "Hello World\n"); 
    var zippromise = zip.generateAsync({ type: "nodebuffer" });
    OfficeHelpers.UI.notify("hello all");
    zippromise.then(function () {
        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify("success")
        // FileSaver.saveAs(content, "example.zip");
    }).catch((error) => {
        OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(error)
    });
} catch (err) {
    OfficeHelpers.UI.notify(err)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using jszip-sync can help to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a good choice if you are using it for browser as synchronization is not recommended for browser ui due to latency issues.

Comment: Hi ankur gupta, welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for submitting an answer; however, your answer doesn't provide a solution to the question that was asked. Please consider editing your answer to address a solution. You can see more about what makes a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer